# PHPUnit: how to create custom annotations for extended exception tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, exception, phpunit

I want to be able to write tests which use a custom annotation to determine whether a test has passed or failed.

I use custom exceptions in my code, which add a getter method to the base Exception class. for example:

```
class MyException extends Exception
{
    // ...
    public function getFoo()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

and I want to be able to write a test which tests that foo is of a given value, like so:

```
class BarTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    /**
     * @expectedException MyException
     * @expectedExceptionFoo 'baz'
     */
    public function testBarThrowsMyExceptionWithFooEqualsBaz()
    {
        $bar = new Bar();
        $bar->throwExceptionWithFooEqualsBaz();
    }
}
```

At the moment I'm working on a solution which involves extending `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`, that overrides `runTest()` but it is becoming ridiculously complicated, since `runTest()` uses so many private methods and class variables, I'm having to rewrite over half the class (some 1200 lines). Is there a simpler way?

One hint at a simpler solution is that `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` has the following methods which might be useful:

- `public    function setUseErrorHandler($useErrorHandler)`
- `protected function setUseErrorHandlerFromAnnotation()`
- `protected function setExpectedExceptionFromAnnotation()`

but I have been trawling through PHPUnit's code to see how I might use them and there is so much indirection with so few comments that right now it's looking like the harder option?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a starting point:

https://codesymphony.co/creating-your-own-phpunit-requires-annotations/

It describes how to implement custom `@requires` annotations, but the code can be used as a jumping point to implement any custom annotation.